# Update metadata SHarePoint

Tags: sharepoint

am new at sharepoint so here is my question if anyone can help me please, trying to update metadata of file that i upload  normaly but when adding the metadata i get an error SytemBagImageFormatException here is the code:
this uploads the file normaly

```
using(PageData pageData = pdfProvider.GetDocument(rendition)
{   
using(Stream stream = pageData.Stream)
{                         Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, destinoArchivo, stream, true);


}               
}
```

but when i do this, i get the error:

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(destinoArchivo);
            context.Load(newFile);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            newFile.CheckOut();


            ListItem listItem = newFile.ListItemAllFields;
            listItem["Clase de Documento"] = "Prueba";
            listItem.Update();

            newFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with it, i can seem to see it, please.